# How can i save a URL text to android registry editor and access it from android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to save a URL to the registry editor of my android phone and get the URL to make an api call in my android application. How can i save a URL to my android phone's registry editor and how can i access to that URL from my android studio application ?

I could not find a way to open the registry editor on an android phone. Is there a way to do this or another way to save the URL i want to use while making the api call on my android phone?

Comment: What is a "registry editor"? If you are referring to Windows' concept of a registry, Android does not have a registry.